# Python Pandas, is there a way to split a date_range into equally sized intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Im currently working on a project in Python (Pandas module). What I want to do is split a date_range into equally sized intervals.

```
import pandas as pd
startdate='2014-08-08'
enddate='2014-08-11'
n=3
pd.date_range(start=startdate,end=enddate)
```

What I would like is some way for it to return the intermediate dates as string, for example:

```
startdate='2014-08-08'
intermediate_1='2014-08-09'
intermediate_2='2014-08-10'
enddate='2014-08-11'
```

This is an example with days, but I would like to be able to do the same for hours or minutes. Is there a way to do this in the current Pandas module? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.split` to split your array, this returns a an array of datetimeindex values so we have to access the value element using `[0]` we can then call the attribute `date()` and cast to str:

```
In [238]:

startdate='2014-08-08'
enddate='2014-08-11'
n=3
d = pd.date_range(start=startdate,end=enddate)
d
Out[238]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-08-08, ..., 2014-08-11]
Length: 4, Freq: D, Timezone: None
In [249]:
# split to produce n-1 blocks
splits = np.split(d, n-1)
# show the contents
for t in splits:
    print(t)
# assign each element, then access the value using [0] and access the date attribute and cast to str
intermediate_1 = str(splits[0][0].date())
intermediate_2 = str(splits[-1][0].date())
# show intermediate_1 which shows it is a str representation of the date
intermediate_1
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-08-08, 2014-08-09]
Length: 2, Freq: D, Timezone: None
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-08-10, 2014-08-11]
Length: 2, Freq: D, Timezone: None
Out[249]:
'2014-08-08'
```

Comment: This seems to work for 3 days, but any other numer of days I try, i get the error: ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
Also, do u know how I can split a day in say, 12 intervals?

Comment: @Alex you have to change the second param to `np.split` you've not specified what you require for equal sized splits but that is not that difficult to set

Comment: @Alex you'd have to resample the index to hours or minutes and then pass 12 as the second param to `np.split`

Comment: @Alex so basically you'd have to create a new index and set the `freq` to `h` or `m` to get an index that is hourly or as minute intervals e.g. `pd.date_range(start = startdate, end = enddate, freq='h')`, however why do you need to do this? typically you resample data to a different frequency rather than a datetimeindex

Comment: Hey, sorry for the slow reply. I've been trying around with the split command and it works great now, thanks. What I use it for is creating multiple plots of time based data. For example, if I get data for a year I want to divide it into four quarters and make a different plot for each quarter. Or for a day, make a different plot for each hour to quickly make the data visual. However it's tedious work to constantly manually determine the intermediate values for the start- and enddate of each seperate plot.

Comment: In that case you just resample the data and split like I've shown and plot the splits, the other thing you can use is the index method  index_slicer but I've never used it so can't advise